# missing font problem

Tags: fonts, hebrew

I have created a simple document using this - `\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}`.
somehow when I compile it dose not recognize the font. The font I use is the default don't from my computer meaning I didn't use a special font package.

I think the problem is the either the *texstudio* does
have the basic font in Hebrew.

how can I install a package with the misssing font?
thx

[image: the erorr]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that generates the error you wish to fix. Please also tell us which program -- pdftex, xetex, or luatex -- you employ to compile your document. Incidentally, the instruction `\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}` does *not*, by itself, specify which font, or fonts, should be used to typeset the document and create a pdf file. And TeXstudio is just a front-end to a TeX distribution; TeXstudio, in and of itself, provides no fonts at all.

Comment: you have not shown enough information to answer but pdftex (which you are using) can not use the system fonts so depending what you mean by "default font from my computer" the missing font message would be expected. You need to specify a Tex font in an 8bit Hebrew encoding. You may prefer to use xelatex or lualatex which can use the system opentype fonts